# Работа с потоками

Tags: windows, потоки-данных, c#

Как повторно запустить поток? Перед повторным запуском потока пробовал делать Abort, но это не то. Есть ли вообще вариант, полной остановки потока?

Comment: Повторно это как? Был запущен поток, потом его останавливаете (как?) и затем не знаете как запустить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос неясен. Вы не можете остановить поток или не знаете, как его запустить снова? Вообще, однажды прибитый или завершившийся поток запустить снова нелья

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9fyxz7d.aspx:

> Once the thread terminates, it cannot be restarted with another call to Start.

Так что если надо перезапустить, то его придётся запустить заново. Старый же нужно завершить. По идее, потоки нельзя просто завершать. Нужно каким-либо способом сообщать ему, что ему пора бы на покой + Interrupt.

UPD: по идее [interrupt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt.aspx) для потока должен прерывать разные операции ожидания. [Abort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx) должен попытаться уничтожить поток. К сожалению, не имею опыта с .NET и не знаю, какова вероятность того, что что-нибудь произойдёт. В Java иногда бывает, что поток нельзя прервать просто так. Например, при чтении из сокета. Тогда приходиться закрывать сокет.

Comment: А как ему это сообщить? что он уже не нужен? Abort?
Да, с потоками не приходилось работать. )
хм. а если повторно создать поток:
th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetProcesses)); ?
так прокатит?

Comment: Да, должно прокатить. Запустится новый (если не забудете сказать ему start).

Answer (score 0):

А чем не устраивает Abort? Попробуйте Interrupt, но это примерно тоже самое что Sleep.

Для корректной остановки потока рекомендуется создавать какой-нибудь объект синхронизации (мьютекс, евент, семафор...) и по его поднятию завершать выполнение потока.

Comment: Есть 2 файла. оба находятся на рахных компах.
Сделал программу, которая сравнивает хэш обеих этих программ в потоке, чтобы программа не висла.
А проверка запускается при нажатии на кнопку.
При втором нажатии - нада сначала поток как - то остановить, чтобы ещё раз его запустить.
в потоке нету while. там идёт единоразовое сравнение, после чего поток на какой - то момент уже не нужен. )

Comment: А почему бы не дождаться завершения предыдущей проверки, прежде чем начинать новую?

Comment: Ну, сетевые операции порой встревают на неопределённый строк...

Comment: Если требуется частая проверка хеша, то  бы стал делать несколько иначе. Создал бы поток и пусть он находиться в постоянном ожидании проверки (по евенту). Евент подняли - проверили хеш - отправили результат и сбросили евент - впали в спячку до следующего поднятия евента. Поток завершается только при завершении программы.

Comment: Неплохой вариант, вот только как вы реализуете "сбросили евент - впали в спячку"? Всё равно придётся писать дополнительный код для отаноки потока. Просто сигнальной переменной не обойтись.

Comment: В самом потоке для того самого евента: Reset а потом WaitOne и ждем Set'а, а если автоматический то без reset'а.

Comment: Если поток заблокируется где-нибудь (например, в чтении из сокета), то он не сможет ничего узнать и никакой wait не может сделать. Тогда придётся делать отдельный управляющий поток, а отдельный - тот который саму работу выполняет, а это как-то накладно.

Comment: Для того чтобы сокеты не блокировались, необходимо использовать асинхронные сокеты, таймауты на операции и прочее. В любом случае, правильно управлять объектом (сокетом, соединением к базе и др.) в том же потоке (процессе и любой другой сущности) который создает этот объект. Поскольку только он знает, что "правильно", а что "неправильно" для этого объекта.

Answer (score 0):

NtSuspendThread/NtResumeThread.
NtSuspendProcess/NtResumeProcess для всех потоков.

Comment: Ой, это не для этого совсем